# Static UITableView, make a single cell with dynamic height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` which has 12 rows and for 11 rows I know what the height needs to be.

I have a UILabel which has dynamic text which sits inside the 12 row, how do i go about making just that one cell to have a dynamic height based on the text in the UILabel.

I have tried the below code inside `viewDidLoad`, but it didn't work. The rows remained the same height. I have also set the **lines = 0** for the `UILabel`

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it didn't work". It's also important to know which of the related methods from `UITableViewDelegate` you have implemented and how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.row < 11) {
        // Everything starts at 0, so this covers 0-10
        // Whatever your cell height is
        return <#fixedCellHeight#>
    } else {
        // This is your 12th cell (indexPath.row 11), as we start counting at 0
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing return in a function expected to return 'CGFloat'

Comment: i changed it around to         if (indexPath.row < 11) {
return 100
        } else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } seems like its working, how can i change the above to be null instead of 100

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Adrian answer , if you are using static Cells , changing one cell to dynamic  height , and others as they are you can edit it to this .

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row == 11 {
      // This is your 12th cell (indexPath.row 11), as we start counting at 0
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
     }
```

Comment: ahhh this is what I was looking for. Forgot `super`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 cell prototype cells for the table view. You give them 2 different id.
And then in your code you override this fonction

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.row < 12 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell12", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can create the dynamic cell with Text height then you can set the static and dynamic cell both in on table view

Here is link to dynamic cell with text How to change cell height dynamically in UITableView static cell

Answer (score 0):

More elegant might be to just implement as suggested:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Or in Objective C:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

But rather than the row specific logic, add constraints to your static cell's content in the [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUCk4.png) to keep the row heights constant. That way if you move rows or change content you don't need to change any code.